# How to put initial data on form in CreateView?

Tags: python, django

I have a view which I'm trying to provide default data using the `get_initial()` function.

But what happens is that it does not appear to execute my attempt to override the said function.

```
class fileCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = file
    success_url=reverse_lazy('file_status:list')
    login_url = 'login'
    form_class = fileForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(fileCreate, self).get_initial()
        initial['name'] = 'this the initial value'
        return initial
```

the redirect and form will render just as expected but it will not show that value that I set for name. Another thing is that when I put a print statement inside the function. it does not show. Why? Is my assumption correct that the `get_initial()` function is not being called?

here my URL call

```
path('new/', views.fileCreate.as_view(), name='create'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks Ok, you can try to add a `print('something')` inside the `get_initial()` to see if it's going inside.

Comment: yep I tried that as well. but I was not able to get any print in the console. I also tried to override get_form_kwargs() and form_valid() but I'm not able to get any print statements in the console. it's really weird, I could have messed up something from the settings or what.

Comment: Can you show your url.py? Maybe you are not using this view at all.

Comment: I added it on the list. I tried to create a new project but still I"m not able to overried the get_initial method. If it would make any difference, I'm using django crud cookie cutter to generate the crud codes

Comment: I think I now know why it's not working. Because I used vanilla to for creating my forms and stuff. I'll continue to test and make it work